# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.manage()" because "com.digite.actions.commands.Common.driver" is null

Tags: java, spring, selenium-webdriver

Created WebDriver in common class and calling in chrome option class, But Throwing null pointer exception.

```
@Component
public class Common extends CommonClass {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Common.class);
    @Autowired
    public static WebDriver driver; // This is where we creating webdriver and calling this webdriver in cromeoption class.

    public static ChromeDriver driver1 = null;
    public WebElement local_element = null;

@Component
public class ChromeDriverOptions extends WebDriverFactory {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChromeDriverOptions.class);

    public ChromeDriverOptions() {
    }
        List<LogEntry> entries = driver.manage().logs().get("performance").getAll(); //This driver still in null. Any suggestion giving life to this driver.

}
```

driver throwing is null pointer exception. Is this issue occurring by dependency compatibility?.

Comment: You should have something like this somewhere in your code:  driver = new ChromeDriver();... along with options if you like.  You're over-complicating things here.  It sounds like you have a "WebDriverFactory" so you could just use that to return your driver instance.  Not sure why you're using these base classes and then extending them.

Comment: @Bean(
        name = {"chromeDriver"}
    )
    @ConditionalOnProperty(
        prefix = "driver",
        name = {"type"},
        havingValue = "chrome"
    )
    public WebDriver chromeDriver() {
        ChromeDriverOptions options = new ChromeDriverOptions();
        this.driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().capabilities(options.setOptions(this.browserMode)).create();
        this.driver.get(this.env);
        return this.driver;
    }
It is inside webdriver factory

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify, code is hard to read in comments. [Edit] your question instead. Make sure it's a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, First Time I posted a Question in Stack Overflow. The question is I'm calling the Common class driver in the chrome option class. But the Chrome option class driver still throws null pointer exceptions. In the common class, the driver is already static.

Comment: I'd suggest you not use common or chromedriveroptions classes.  Just use the webdriverfactory that will return the driver instance to use throughout your code.